# ASP.NET 4.0 Route expression builder inside Listview control

Tags: asp.net, routes

One of the features of ASP.NET 4.0 is Route Expression builder which allows you to set up hyperlinks like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink 
    runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl="<%$ RouteUrl:RouteName=productos,categoria=Cereales,id=2 %>" >Productos</asp:HyperLink>
```

Now I'm wondering if I can use this sort of syntax inside a ListView Control,  I know is possible, but the tricky thing is that I want to genereate de route key value dynamically.
So instead to write id=2 I would like to write  id=<%# Eval("CategoryID") %> .

Can I do that?, if so, how should I write it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have searched and searched for an example did not find a way to handle building routes in an expression builder. I finally figured out a way to do this in a gridview, maybe you can adapt? See my post at the following address where I answered my own question: [How to use routing in web forms and HyperLinkFields of a GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111110/how-to-use-routing-in-web-forms-and-hyperlinkfields-of-a-gridview/4138746#4138746)

I think an asp hyperlink control will not work because the controls are built before the Eval() is called, but an anchor is just text so it works within a template field.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you can do it with the Route ExpressionBuilder. Instead you can give an ID to the Hyperlink object in the .aspx file:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="productHyperLink" runat="server">Productos</asp:HyperLink>
```

And set the NavigateUrl property in the Page_Load method in the .cs file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int categoryId;
    string categoryName;

    // Get categoryId and categoryName from database

    RouteValueDictionary values = new RouteValueDictionary {
        { "id", categoryId.ToString() },
        { "categoria", categoryName } };
    VirtualPathData virtualPathData = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, "productos", values);
    productHyperLink.NavigateUrl = virtualPathData.VirtualPath;
}
```